# Sorting rows from one sheet to another, skipping the first row

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I am redesigning some spreadsheets for my work, and one of them is just a big list of events that we have/are going to host.

My issue is, I would like for the first sheet to be the one where all the data is imported and maintained for future events, but will not be placed in order, i.e. soonest event will most likely not be first and so on. The second sheet I would like to sort the first sheets data based on the date column. And the last sheet will be for past events.

So, my issue is that I found this function to sort the data in the first sheet into the second sheet:

```
=sort(Sheet1!A:J, 2,TRUE)
```

And it works exactly how I need it to, minus I can't figure out how to skip the first row on the first sheet so it doesn't sort the headers also.

Here is a sample of what the first few rows look like:

[image]

I feel like it is something simple that I am missing but just can't seem to figure it out. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is specify the range starting from the second row in the sheet using `A2:J`, rather than the whole sheet `A:J`:

```
=SORT(Sheet1!A2:J, 2,TRUE)
```

Comment: I figured it was something simple like that, worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

for short:

```
=SORT(Sheet1!A2:J, 2, 1)
```

but also you can use `QUERY` in which you can freeze the header row from sorting

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:J, "order by B", 1)
```

or like:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:J, "where B is not null order by B", 1)
```